# Socialite is not working in Laravel Middleware, How can i resolve this issue?

Tags: laravel, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite for Google Authentication, i have an middleware for check that if user exist in my local database by their google_id, it can redirect to **/home** page otherwise it will redirect back to Google Authentication page, while doing this i am facing issue in middle and the error is:

**Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }**

> Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
//use Socialite;
use App\GmailAccount;
use Closure;

use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GoogleAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

        $finduser = GmailAccount::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

        if($finduser){
            return $next($request);
        }

        else{
            return route('/logingoogle');
        }

    }
}
```

> Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\GoogleAuth'], function()
{
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

});

Route::get('/logingoogle', 'GoogleController@google_login');

Route::get('auth/google', 'GoogleController@redirectToGoogle');

Route::get('auth/google/callback', 'GoogleController@handleGoogleCallback');
```

> HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        $this->middleware('googleauth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $user_messages=DB::table('user_message')
            ->join('messages', 'user_message.message_id', '=', 'messages.id')
            ->where([
            'user_message.user_id' => $user_id,
            'user_message.placeholder' => 'inbox'
                ])
            ->select('messages.*', 'user_message.message_id', 'user_message.user_id','user_message.is_read')
            ->orderBy('messages.id', 'DESC')

            ->paginate(10);
        return view('website_pages.home',compact('user_messages'));
    }
}
```

> GoogleController

```
class GoogleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function google_login(){

        return  view('website_pages.login_google');

    }

    public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleGoogleCallback()
    {

            $login_user_id  =  Auth::user()->id;

        try {

            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

            $finduser = GmailAccount::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

            if($finduser){
                return redirect('/home');
            }
            else{
                $newUser = DB::table('gmail_accounts')->updateOrInsert(
                    [
                        'email' => $user->email,
                    ],

                    [
                    'user_id' => $login_user_id,
                     'email' => $user->email,
                    'google_id'=> $user->id,
                    'remember_token'=> $user->token
                ]

                );

                if ($newUser){
                    return redirect('/home');
                }

                else{
                    return redirect()->back();
                }
                Auth::login($newUser, true);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> GmailAccount Model

```
class GmailAccount extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'gmail_accounts';


    protected $fillable = [
       'email', 'password', 'google_id', 'user_id', 'remember_token'
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
if($finduser) {
    auth()->login($finduser), true);
}
else {
    return redirect('/logingoogle');
}
```

Comment: Error is gone, but this statement run in loop , how can i solve this
return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();

Comment: I just use this line in my Existing Middleware at the beginning of handle function 

return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();

Comment: What happens if you remove stateless function? If you dont paste full code for each file nobody can help you.

Comment: Now, you can see my controller as-well

Comment: When i remove stateless function, same issue occure

Comment: Bro, by this link i implement it and its working fine, but when i use this on middleware it can create issue.

Comment: I Pasted the Model Code please check it

Comment: You have lot's of problems in that code. Your model doesn't extends Authenticatable as User models does for working with Authentication.

Comment: Comment all your code and follow the link I sent and use the same controllers, models and routes. Once is working, you can change your code and test.

Comment: Did you solve this @SaadMasood ?
It will be great if you mark my answers, it's important for people that helps other to give mark them answers when you recieve help.

Answer (score 0):

And include these:

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
 use Socialite;`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this which is a working example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Socialite;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        // check if they're an existing user
        $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();

        if ($existingUser) {
            // log them in
            auth()->login($existingUser, true);
        } else {
            // create a new user
            $newUser                  = new User;
            $newUser->name            = $user->name;
            $newUser->email           = $user->email;
            $newUser->google_id       = $user->id;
            $newUser->avatar          = $user->avatar;
            $newUser->avatar_original = $user->avatar_original;
            $newUser->lastlogin_at    = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
            $newUser->save();
            auth()->login($newUser, true);
        }
        session(['user_name' => $user->name]);
        session(['user_email' => $user->email]);
        session(['user_avatar' => $user->avatar]);

        return redirect()->to('/home');
    }
}
```

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: Yes i tried this, is working fine but when i do this in middleware error occurs :(